# How to dynamically set align property for td in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, my question is in the comment:

```
function (align) {    
    var column = $(`'<td>'`);  
  // now i need syntax to set align property to this td element  
  // column.align = align (not working)  
}
```

As shown, `column.align = align` is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've edited your tags to include JQuery and edited your question to improve its quality. Please feel free to refine my edits if any are in error. In the future, please be a little more specific, it will help you get great answers faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it seems you're using jQuery, so you can do something like :

```
column.attr('align', 'right');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one:**

```
$(column).attr("align","left");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using jQuery? Use `column.attr('align', 'whatev')` or better yet, use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the `$` selector, you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**In that case, `column` is not a DOM element, but a [jQuery selector result](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), and you have to treat it accordingly:**

```
$(column).attr('align', 'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
myTD.setAttribute("align", "right");